# Acessing object inside a fucntion in python

Tags: python

**jira_formatting.py**

```
from .xml_parsing import xml2jira
from ._utility import *
from .get_global_constants import get_global_constants
import os

def get_tables_IOs(__filename, lang):
    
    if not os.path.exists(__filename):
        print("File not found!")
        exit(1)
    pkg_name = get_pkg_name(__filename)
    obj = xml2jira(lang)

    return pkg_name
```

**test_jira_formatting.py**

```
import unittest
import sys
import os
from unittest.mock import patch
from modules.jira_formatting import *
from pathlib import Path

pcakge_path = 'C:/TEMP/020_Tests/CCN-4679.pkg'
path = Path(pcakge_path)
lang = "en_US"


class TestJiraFormatting(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_description_in_lines(self):
        pkg_name, descriptions = get_description_in_lines(path, lang)
        self.assertEqual(pkg_name, "CCN-4679")

    @patch("modules.xml_parsing")
    def test_get_tables_IOs(self, mock_xmlparsing_constructor):
        mock_parsing = mock_xmlparsing_constructor(lang).return_value
        self.assertIs(get_tables_IOs(path, lang).obj, mock_parsing)
```

Why I am not able to access this `get_tables_IOs(path, lang).obj`

Comment: it's a local variable. just return it to get access to it `return pkg_name,obj` now you have a tuple

Comment: Local variables do not automagically become part of the return value of the function; they just disappear when the function returns unless you explicitly `return` them.

Comment: nope I can not change the code in jira_formatting.py. Becasue I am writing a unit testing code for jira_formatting.py in test_jira_formatting.py

Comment: Then how can I mock this object?